# Specta and delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

How can I test protocols and delegates in Specta? I have the following code:

```
#import "Specta.h"
#import "SBSearchService.h"


SpecBegin(SearchService)

describe(@"Search Manager", ^{

    __block SBSearchService *searchService;

    beforeAll(^{
        searchService = [[SBSearchService alloc] init];
        searchService.delegate = self;
    });

    it(@"returns at least 1 result", ^AsyncBlock {
        [searchService search:@"mustang"];
    });
});

SpecEnd
```

I would like to know what is the syntax to specify that the test conforms to a protocol in Specta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Expecta](https://github.com/specta/expecta) for that. So it would go along these lines:

```
searchService.conformTo(@protocol(aProtocol)
```